# get the bar index when a condition is true using a for loop

Tags: for-loop, statistics, pine-script, correlation, pine-script-v5

```
offset = 10 
lookback = 100
var corr_true = false
var barind = 0
var bar_ind_array = array.new<int>(0)
length = for i = offset to lookback + offset
    length = i 
    length
test_sim = if barstate.isnew and ((get_corr[length] > 0 and get_corr > 0) or (get_corr[length] < 0 and get_corr < 0) ? get_corr[length] - get_corr : get_corr[length] + get_corr) <= 0.005
    barind := bar_index[length]
    corr_true := true 
else 
    if ((get_corr[length] > 0 and get_corr > 0) or (get_corr[length] < 0 and get_corr < 0) ? get_corr[length] - get_corr : get_corr[length] + get_corr) >= 0.05
        corr_true := false 
if test_sim 
    array.push(bar_ind_array, barind)
```

I am trying to use a for loop to check whether the correlation of the current bar is within a certain amount of similarity to any bar over the last (i) bars. The problem im having is when the correlation of the current bar is found to be similar to that of another bar, how to extract the bar index of the bar which the current one is similar to.

Iv'e tried it many ways both using arrays and without, ive hit multiple different types of errors and have yet to find a working solution although im positive theirs one out there. Any help would be appreciated!

When I try to reference a bar thats similar to the current bar using the `array.get()` function, it says array size is zero, however when i reference the array size using `array.size()` it returns greater than zero.

Comment: Normally, you loop historical bars using `[]` opeator, e.g. `high[1]` for previous bar's `high`. The bar index of the previous bar will be `bar_index[1]`.

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: I updated it with some code of the most recent way I tried it and a little more expanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the index of `for` starting from 1 and subtract it from the `bar_index`: `bar_index-i`

```
for i = 1 to X
            if CONDITION[i] // check the condition on the i candle before
                // bar_index-i
```

for example you can run this sample:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay=true)
if last_bar_index == bar_index
    for i = 1 to 5
        if high[i] > 28000
            label.new(bar_index-i,high,str.tostring(bar_index)+"\n"+str.tostring(bar_index-i))
```

The problem with `array` is that you must have been pushed the previous candle already and I don't think it is a good choice for your problem.

Comment: this worked great with a little modification thanks!, say I needed the values to also get into arrays to use as training data how could I do this?

Comment: @SheaAbernethy Glad that I could help. If i understood what you are saying then you can use array.get (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array.get)